# depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname

Tags: apt, linux-kernel, dpkg

I get the following error:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8. 8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-uname
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/uname
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
E: No boot partition found !
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.8.0.52.23); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-uname
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/uname
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
E: No boot partition found !
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
 initramfs-tools
```

It appears that somehow, `uname` instead of `uname -r` is being passed around, which is making the application unable to know the correct kernel version of my system. Or it may be something else, I don't know...

I am currently unable to install (or reinstall) any package through sudo apt. Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found an solution to the problem via [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524179/apt-get-dist-upgrade-reports-error-depmod-error-bad-version-passed-uname-a#comment969381_524179) in this question: ["apt-get dist-upgrade" reports error "depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname" and various warnings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524179/apt-get-dist-upgrade-reports-error-depmod-error-bad-version-passed-uname-a) :

You need to delete everything, that is not in the form `uname -r` reports from under `/var/lib/initramfs-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, and just downgrade `linux-firmware` package

```
    sudo apt install linux-firmware=1.157
    sudo apt-mark hold linux-firmware
```

on any newer version of this package - `Bad version passed uname`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/197416)

Comment: @steve why not? The answer is basically suggesting downgrading the firmware package. Assuming it works, that seems like a decent workaround.